# XSL v.1, Muenchian Grouping, Summing Line Items per Invoice, Call-Template

Tags: sum, xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

I'm trying to sum the aggregate of line item amounts in a group with multiple groups. That is, there are many Invoices with many Line Items per Invoice. I need to sum the Amounts of Line Items across each Invoice.

I've searched across various posts here on Stack, as well as various forums, and haven't been able to decipher the code to be able to sum values with a Muenchian Grouping approach. If there is already a solution for this, please point me in the right direction.

The grouping occurs on the `recordId` attribute.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query>
    <results total="6">
        <result recordId="15918960" associatedRecordId="null" boId="10002385">
            <columns>
                <column>
                    <field>AmountNU</field>
                    <LI_Amount_display><![CDATA[$20.74]]></LI_Amount_display>
                </column>
            </columns>
        </result>
        <result recordId="15918960" associatedRecordId="null" boId="10002385">
            <columns>
                <column>
                    <field>AmountNU</field>
                    <LI_Amount_display><![CDATA[$30.74]]></LI_Amount_display>
                </column>
            </columns>
        </result>
        <result recordId="15918960" associatedRecordId="null" boId="10002385">
            <columns>
                <column>
                    <field>AmountNU</field>
                    <LI_Amount_display><![CDATA[$40.74]]></LI_Amount_display>
                </column>
            </columns>
        </result>
        <result recordId="15918961" associatedRecordId="null" boId="10002385">
            <columns>
                <column>
                    <field>AmountNU</field>
                    <LI_Amount_display><![CDATA[$20.74]]></LI_Amount_display>
                </column>
            </columns>
        </result>
        <result recordId="15918961" associatedRecordId="null" boId="10002385">
            <columns>
                <column>
                    <field>AmountNU</field>
                    <LI_Amount_display><![CDATA[$30.74]]></LI_Amount_display>
                </column>
            </columns>
        </result>
        <result recordId="15918962" associatedRecordId="null" boId="10002385">
            <columns>
                <column>
                    <field>AmountNU</field>
                    <LI_Amount_display><![CDATA[$29.74]]></LI_Amount_display>
                </column>
            </columns>
        </result>       
    </results>
</query>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:datetime="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2013/xpath-functions"
exclude-result-prefixes="datetime">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:key name="recordID" match="result" use="@recordId"/><!-- Define a key to use for grouping the results -->
    <!-- Might be needed for nulls 
    <xsl:template match="/results/result/columns/column/LI_Amount_display[not(text()[normalize-space()])]"> 
    <xsl:element name='LI_Amount_display' value="0.00"></xsl:element> 
    </xsl:template> -->    

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="fixTheWidth" >
            <!-- This parameter is a Id for each group of records based on the result/@recordId attribute. This groups all records to the record ID-->
            <xsl:with-param name="resultIndex" select="//results/result[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('recordID', @recordId)[1])]" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="fixTheWidth" match="/results">
        <xsl:param name="resultIndex" /> <!-- A unique index based on grouping the records on the recordID -->

<!-- MORE CODE HERE USING $resultIndex has been redacted for simplicity-->

        <xsl:for-each select="$resultIndex" >
            <xsl:text> BEGIN | </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="number(translate(substring(key('recordID',@recordId)/columns/column/LI_Amount_display,2),',',''))"></xsl:value-of>
                <!-- <xsl:value-of select="sum(number(translate(substring(key('recordID',@recordId)/columns/column/LI_Amount_display,2),',','')))"></xsl:value-of>-->
        </xsl:for-each>   
         <xsl:text> | END  </xsl:text>


<!-- MORE CODE HERE USING $resultIndex has been redacted for simplicity-->


    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I realize that using the "call-template" strategy is not necessarily the "best" approach, but its what I've come to such that I can create a fixed width flat file and not have to refactor the entire script. If there's a way to accomplish this otherwise, I'm all ears.

Comment: Why does your stylesheet include a reference to a  `columns/column/LI_Amount` node which does not exist in your input?

Comment: it should be /LI_Amount_display. I took out extraneous code to simplify for this post. My apologies for not proofreading it more effectively. I have edited it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sum nodes that aren't numbers. A value of `$20.74` is a string, not a number. You must first convert the values to numbers by removing the currency symbol (and any other non-numeric characters, if they are allowed in the input), then proceed to group the resulting nodes and sum the groups.

Here's an example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="amt" match="amount" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="/query">
    <xsl:variable name="amounts">
        <xsl:for-each select="results/result">
            <amount id="{@recordId}"><xsl:value-of select="translate(columns/column/LI_Amount_display, '$', '')"/></amount>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="amount-set" select="exsl:node-set($amounts)/amount" />

    <xsl:for-each select="$amount-set[generate-id() = generate-id(key('amt', @id)[1])]" >
        <xsl:text> BEGIN | </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('amt', @id))"/>
    </xsl:for-each>   
    <xsl:text> | END  </xsl:text> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, the result is:

```
 BEGIN | 92.22 BEGIN | 51.48 BEGIN | 29.74 | END
```

I couldn't understand the strategy of calling a template and "create a fixed width flat file". In any case, it seems unrelated to the question at hand. You might post a separate question, if necessary.

Comment: I've tried this and I can get it to work as you've written it. But if I attempt to put it inside the 'fixTheWidth' template and also maintaining the current $resultIndex grouping. It currently iterates through each $resultIndex aligning the output of each invoice, and all of its Line Items before moving on to the next. The piece of code in question is to sum all the Line Items as the Gross amount and output it in a header row that contains information about the Invoice.

Comment: @RebelPhoenix As I said, I could not understand what you're doing, so I cannot advise how to incorporate my suggestion in that. Either expand your question and explain the additional requirements, or post a new one.